# Can a mobile app blur the screen?

Tags: android, ios, smartphone

Is it possible a mobile app working like a background process to blur or fade the screen of the smartphone, no matter what active app is being displayed? Does the android and ios APIs expose such features?

Comment: I cannot speak for android, but for iOS no way! 1. You cant run anything as a background process for ever 2. No such API that would allow app to blur the screens of other App

Comment: How can you not run anything as a background process forever when there are plenty apps working that way?

Comment: in iOS ??? Please enlighten me with such apps sir :D No buddy, you cant I have already answered an answer regarding the same in the past lemme know if I could post the link here

Comment: There are specific background execution modes for iOS for things like Bluetooth, audio, location etc, but an iOS app cannot affect the screen if it isn't the foreground app

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not on Android. There are accessibility services which do modify the screen regardless of which app is visible but those are mostly first party applications. It would be a pretty big security risk issue if apps could block/blur the screen of other apps.

That being said you can create an overlay which lets touches through. I'm not sure if you can get the actual pixels of the UI behind the overlay and run a blur yourself but you can draw over top of elements on the screen (using accessibility APIs you can get the positions of UI elements) which may suit your needs depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: On certain conditions I want to blur the whole screen of the phone regardless of what is displayed

Comment: AFAIK that's not something that can be done. Your best bet is to check the Android accessibility APIs which **may** allow you to get the actual screen pixels and then you can run a blur yourself but it would be difficult to make it run quickly and your app would be an 'accessibility service' which the average user wouldn't install without a good reason.